# Installation of Ubuntu 19.10 on INTEL RST

Tags: raid, intel, rst

I used Linux a long, long time ago(in 1999, using RedHat 6.0 I'm not mistaken).

Just for curiosity, I  started using Linux again with Ubuntu and got surprised how things evolved.

There is one thing though, which I can't make it work at all, which is to make ubuntu understand the disk arrays.

I have 2 arrays of disks:
First with 3 SSDs in RAID 0
Second with two hard disks in RAID 1

The arrays were built using the Intel RAID RST, hard disks are configured to be used in RAID mode instead of AHCI.

Before installing anything I already performed a backup of the data and unplugged my second array of hard disks from the machine.
If I lose the array of SSDs I don't care, the worst thing that can happen is that I will have to do is to reinstall OS.

My issue is:
Once I boot Ubuntu 19.10, it identifies two volumes of hard disks related to my SSD.
I tried to delete the partitions and create just a new one (mounting to / ) however when I clicked OK the system simply hangs.

I rebooted the machine and the Windows installation was still there, so Ubuntu didn't touch the array.

Is Ubuntu 19.10 supporting Intel RST hardware arrays?
My motherboard is an ASUS Maximus VI formula with a Z87 chipset.

Thanks so much in advance.
FucaBala

Comment: I have a similar problem with a SSD in RST mode that Ubuntu 18.04 won't see (at all). I know I can change the SSD to AHCI (many questions and answers out there to link one here) with some headache if Windows was already installed and with some loss of performance in Windows. I was searching for info about Ubuntu 19.10 compatibility with Intel RST, to try it before giving up, and your unanswered question did help me: I won't try it.

Comment: I also have RST and can switch to AHCI to run the Ubuntu installer but it can't see the Windows partitions. Disastor, is dual boot now dead?!